# The meaning of 'implicate' here

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from an article in the CBC news:[Is there a path to redemption for any of the high-profile men accused of sexual misconduct?](http://www.cbc.ca/news/opinion/harassment-analysis-1.4424914)

> Marcus has a point. That's not to suggest men like Harvey Weinstein,
>   who embody a particularly heinous sort of sexual predator — those who
>   not only victimize prey, but **implicate** all those around by terrorizing
>   them into silence — deserve any shot at redemption. Nor do men who
>   prey on children.

I tried to apply different entries of '[implicate](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/implicate)' to the sentence to figure out the context, but am confused. 
**'3. to affect as a consequence'** seems to work. But one of the synonyms '[**incriminate**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/implicate?q=implicate)' seems to fit the context as well. What is your take on it?

Comment: **involve, compromise, embroil, entangle, inculpate** = to make them the silent accomplices of his misdeeds

Comment: Thank you. Why do I always choose the wrong one, I wonder --;;

Comment: Don't hurry to blame yourself; it's just my (NNS) opinion. Let's wait for native speakers' comments.

Comment: I do not think the quote is a very well written sentence. The point may be that the perpetrator attempts to blame the victims.

Comment: The gist is that Weinstein made those around him accomplices to his actions by intimidating them into silence and acceptance of his behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He implicates those around the victim and in the workspace:  He makes sure that secretaries and assistants and possibly even friends of the victims will keep quiet about anything they see.

> Cause someone to bear some of the responsibility for (an action or process, especially a criminal or harmful one)<sub>[Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implicate)</sub>

Comment: To *cause* someone to bear.... When someone implicates you, you are implicated. You can also implicate yourself, of course.  *When I asked you to lie for me, and say I was with you on the night of the 10th, I implicated you in the crime.*

Comment: I added the “cause someone” - I contemplated _..anything they see, to make them bear..._